# How to finish other activity when back button is pressed in splash activity?

Tags: java, android

So im working on slideshow-like project, but my problem is, when im at the middle of slideshow, I want to go back at my main activity where my slideshow will start using back button on my smartphone. What happen is, it will go back as soon as I pressed back button, but the other slideshows will carry on after 3 seconds which I set in my `handler.postDelayed(r1, 3000);`. Please help. Thank you

```
public class Dad1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dad1);

        Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Dad2.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        };
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(r1, 3000);

    }
}
```

Comment: im confused. seems like you're complaining about the delay that you have intentionally added

Comment: no, my problem is that, i do not want to carry on, on the rest of the splash activity(slideshow-like) as soon as I press the back button when im at the middle of the slideshow. What happen is that, if I pressed the back button, I will go back to my main activity(that is fine), but the other splash activities will still carry on and I dont want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is keep the `Handler` object at the `Activity` level. When back button is pressed then just cancel the `Handler callbacks`. So in that case your Handler's `run` method will not be called.

Please find the sample code below:

```
   public class Dad1 extends AppCompatActivity {

private Handler handler;

private Runnable myRunnable;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    initRunnable();
    handler.postDelayed(myRunnable,3000);
}

private void initRunnable() {
    myRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Dad2.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    };
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    if(handler!=null){
        handler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please check now

Comment: do I need to create removeCallbacks method? and how? Sorry Im a beginner

Comment: Yes because in you onCreate method you have added a run method and now when user is navigating back, you don't want handler to open Dad2 class soo thats why you need to remove callback from the handler.

Comment: Please look the method onBackPressed Method in the above code

Comment: in removeCallbacks you need to pass Runnable you have added in Handler